# Carousel animation flutter with photos

Tags: flutter

I want to do a carousel animation with photos that starts by itself and doesn't need to be touch to move the photos (slide)and the photos to go to the right . The app that i am working in it's flutter .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) flutter package to achieve this. You can refer to the [GitHub](https://github.com/serenader2014/flutter_carousel_slider) for documentation.

In Short,

Add carousel_slider: ^2.2.1 to your pubspec.yaml

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
```

Simply create a CarouselSlider widget, and pass the required params:

```
pass autoPlay option as true on CarouselOptions()
```

```
CarouselSlider(
  options: CarouselOptions(
            height: 400.0,
            enableInfiniteScroll: true,
            autoPlay: true
  ),
  items: [1,2,3,4,5].map((i) {
    return Builder(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.amber
          ),
          child: Text('text $i', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),)
        );
      },
    );
  }).toList(),
)
```